# Easyadmin issues a lot of querys when filtering and the CRUD class has the @UniqueEntity constraint

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms, easyadmin

I have a problem when filtering at the index page of a CRUD.

The CRUD class is **Product**, if a filter by an association (**Brand** in my case), a lot of queries are issued if the **Product** class has the `@UniqueEntity` constraint.

**To Reproduce**

- **Product** entity class with the constraint on top and its related `brand` entity

```
...
 * @UniqueEntity(fields={"name"})
 */
class Product
{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=Brand::class, inversedBy="products")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=true, onDelete="SET NULL")
     */
    private $brand;
```

- **Brand** class has the inverse side defined too:

```
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=Product::class, mappedBy="brand", cascade={"persist"})
     */
    private $products;
```

- I have a CRUD controller for the **Product** entity.
- I added an `EntityFilter` for brands in the filters section:

```
  public function configureFilters(Filters $filters): Filters
  {
      return $filters
          ->add(EntityFilter::new('brand', 'Brand'));
  }
```

When i enter a brand in the filter popup and apply, a lot of querys are issued. It is like it is trying to revalidate that the name is unique for each filtered product. Querys are like this (one for each filtered product):

`SELECT ... FROM product t0 WHERE t0.name = 'similique culpa non rerum rem in assumenda' LIMIT 2;`

*"similique culpa non rerum rem in assumenda"* being the name of one of the filtered products.

If i remove the `@UniqueEntity(fields={"name"})` constraint, the queries are not issued.

**Version of Easy Admin bundle is 4.0**

Thanks a lot!

**UPDATE**: Well i think the problem comes when you have the inverse side of the relation defined too. In my example, if i define the `OneToMany` **"brand.products"** inverse side of the relation, then, filtering by a brand issues the queries (i guess it is a matter of how the filter form, on the `handleRequest` call, recursively finds and validates constraints). If i remove the inverse side of the relation in **Brand**, no queries are issued.

In small applications this maybe no problem but, in my case, i have brands with thousands of products and, if i filter by such brands, a query is issued for each product, so that's no minor problem.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem in my case - adding UniqueEntity and nothing happens. Do you have valid primary key for your entity?

Comment: @aso have you added also the inverse side in the Product - Brand relation? I mean the OneToMany "brand.products"?